# net.ipv4.ip_forward not peristent, even in /etc/sysctl.conf

Tags: debian, networking, boot, sysctl

Currently i'm setting up a new Debian 11 Bullseye machine to act as a Wireguard gateway.
Everything as usual, and simple.
Unfortunately i am having a heavy issue regarding the IPV4 packet forwarding.
It's a well known fact, that i have to uncomment `#net.ipv4.ip_forward` in the `/etc/sysctl.conf` file, to enable packet forwarding.
Unfortunately,even when it's uncommented, the setting is not being applied automatically after reboot.
I have to manually process the sysctl file using "sysctl -p" every time after reboot.
What's wrong here? There is also no further sysctl.conf in sysctl.conf.d which may override this setting.
I have also tried on a fresh Debian 11 system, with the same issue.

```
root@wireguard:~# /sbin/sysctl --system
* Applying /etc/sysctl.d/1-sysctl.conf ...
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding = 1
* Applying /usr/lib/sysctl.d/50-pid-max.conf ...
kernel.pid_max = 4194304
* Applying /usr/lib/sysctl.d/protect-links.conf ...
fs.protected_fifos = 1
fs.protected_hardlinks = 1
fs.protected_regular = 2
fs.protected_symlinks = 1
* Applying /etc/sysctl.conf ...
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding = 1
```

After reboot:

```
root@wireguard:~# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
0
root@wireguard:~# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/forwarding
1
```

I hope someone can help me, it looks like, it's being partially applied only, i don't know if it has something to do with the IPv6 setting. Everything apart from the sysctl.conf and the Wireguard install is set to default.

Comment: Are you using ufw? If yes, see if there is such an option inside /etc/ufw/sysctl.conf . Also, leave net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1 only in sysctl.conf

Answer (score 2):

Create a `/etc/sysctl.d/99-ipv.conf` with the following lines:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding = 1
```

Then run:

```
sudo systemctl restart  procps
sudo sysctl -p
```

Comment: perfect answer, thanks!